# Unable to open notepad through console in Windows 7

Tags: windows, command-line, java

if I type

```
notepad Hi,java
```

I am getting an error as

```
notepad is not recognized as internal or external command
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Check how you path is defined.

E.g. start cmd.exe, then type `echo %%path%%`. It should include %windir%\system32.

[image]

If it is not in your path then add it. You can do this in several ways; the easiest is way probably via [My computer] *right click* [Properties] *advanced system settings*, tab [advanced], button [Environment variables]

Note that %windir%\system32\ is in the path by default. In order not to have it someone either removed it, or you or an installer  set a new path **replacing** the old path. (Probably when you wanted to append to the path).

Comment: You don't need two percent signs. `echo %PATH%` is enough. Or just `path`.